# Fontforge script export to png with transparent background

Tags: fonts, png, fontforge

I'm using fontforge and a python script to export font icons to png files.

```
import os
from fontforge import *

font = open(os.sys.argv[1])
for glyph in font:
    if font[glyph].isWorthOutputting():
        font[glyph].export(font[glyph].glyphname + ".png")
```

The icons have a white background. I would like to have a transparent background but i've not been able to find documentation about this. is there a way to have a transparent background?